# Where should API tokens be stored in the client app?

Tags: android

```
Android Studio 3.4 Canary 7
```

I am using clean architecture in my android app.

I have the following modules:

```
data, domain, presentation, and mobileUI
```

I am using mapbox API and I have a token.

I am planning to store this token in a file called Constants.kt in the mobileUI maybe in a package called core to keep all common things together.

Just wondering if this is the standard practice to keep tokens. Should it be in the shared preferences instead?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Personally, I keep them as String resources in an xml file named api_keys. I also think this will be form to personal preference.

Comment: Actually, think twice before putting private API key in your app. Any person could extract it, and then use it in his app or directly. The preferred method, if possible,  is keeping the api_key on your server, and have your server proxy the requests. This will give you much more control and security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think shared preferences is good and common to keep a token if you get the token from action like login or also maybe you can make a text file that contains the token, so its stored in user storage